# How to get each file data in jQuery when I select multiple files?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get each file data when I select multiple files?

```
<input name="file" type="file" multiple="" >

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(':file').change(function(){
    var file = this.files[0];
    name = file.name.toLowerCase();
    size = file.size;
    type = file.type;
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this.files` will produce an array. So just loop through like this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(':file').change(function(){
    for(var i=0; i< this.files.length; i++){
       var file = this.files[i];
       name = file.name.toLowerCase();
       size = file.size;
       type = file.type;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this -

```
$(':file').change(function(){
    var fileArray = this.files;
    $.each(fileArray,function(i,v){
      name = v.name.toLowerCase();
      size = v.size;
      type = v.type;
      alert(name);
    })
});
```

Comment: Thank you this solution it made my day as I was trying to access the .each function directly which in result return error